# cvs, "file should be removed and is still there (or back again)"

Tags: version-control, cvs

I am trying to commit a project in which a file has been "cvs remove"d, but actually needs to be there.  The contents has been completely rewritten, but it needs to retain the same name.

I am unable to either commit the project or re-add the file without getting this annoying error message.  How do I "unremove" a file in CVS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Rename the file

   ```
   mv mistakenly_removed_file wtf
   ```
2. Ask cvs to add the old version:

   ```
   cvs add mistakenly_removed_file
   ```
3. cvs then reports it has resurrected the removed file.

   ```
   mv wtf mistakenly_removed_file
   ```

`cvs status` reveals that the file is now "locally modified"

Comment: I was hit by the same problem today. The cvs commandline is really hard to use and I'm really happy you got a workaround. Sidenote: I personally love the name of the temporary file.

Comment: A sense of humour is vital in this biz :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cvs add FILE
```

Or, alternatively, if you want to get the latest copy back from the repository

```
cvs update -C FILE
```

Comment: Sadly neither of these answers worked for me.(the question does say I can't re-add the file) For some reason we are using version '1.9.28' cicra 1998, so CVS is even more annoying than normal