# can't commit code after renaming a file

Tags: version-control, cvs, commit

What I did:

1. renamed a file
2. tried to commit
3. cvs fails with error message

   > file should be removed and is still there (or back again)

What is the problem and how do I solve it so that I can commit?

---

Additional information:

- I'm using Eclipse with the CVS plugin.
- doing an `ls` in the directory where the file was shows that it is **not** there

All the other Google hits for this problem (including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287401/cvs-file-should-be-removed-and-is-still-there-or-back-again)) seem to be asking what to do when a file has been removed with cvs, and then restored outside of cvs' scope.  My problem is different:  I just need to rename a file.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the file was flagged for deletion by CVS but then appeared again. Renaming for CVS is just a deletion of the file with old name and adding the file with new name. The file must be appeared again with its old name.

You can do 2 things:

1) If you don't need this file then just delete it. (Use `cvs -n update` command to find its name.) Then you will be able to commit.

1) if you need this file to stay, go to the `.CVS` subfolder of the folder where the file is located and edit `Entries` file. Find a line with your file and delete it. Then rename you file (give it a temporary name), call `cvs update`, rename your file back overriding the new one appeared after `cvs update`.